# WSO2 IS Custom authenticator with property files

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating a custom authenticator in WSO2 IS 5.11 and I need to create some property files in server, i.e, repository/conf/myproperties.properties to load them from the custom authenticator. I always get  "access denied". How can I set this property files in the server and read them properly in the custom authenticator?

Cheers

Comment: Instead of creating new property files, you can use `<is-home>/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` to define a new custom authenticator and its properties. won't that approach meet your requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to load the properties from a new properties file, add the file into the preferred location of IS and write the logic to read your file and load the properties into a data holder during the OSGi service activation.
   That file reading and storing logic need to be invoked in the  `activate(ComponentContext ctxt)` method mentioned in step 3 of
   https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/#configurations.
2. As an alternative option you can use the `<is-home>/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` file to store your custom authenticators properties. The following configs need to be applied in to
   `<is-home>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file.
   (NOTE: <cutom_alias>,  should be replaced)

```
[authentication.authenticator.<cutom_alias>]
name = "<CustomeAuthenticatorName>"
enable = true

[authentication.authenticator.<cutom_alias>.parameters]
param1 = "value1"
param2 = "value2"
```

That file reading logic already implemented and you can retrieve the params by `getAuthenticatorConfig()` method in `AbstractApplicationAuthenticator` class.`getAuthenticatorConfig().getParameterMap();` can be used to load the defined parameters. (eg:
https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-basicauth/blob/6b6ae8d452397f26f948a870e72e8086b46669c9/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/basicauth/BasicAuthenticator.java#L203)